# Lightbox won't work after ajax content update

Tags: ajax, wordpress, lightbox

I have a calendar http://tinyurl.com/bn9r6lk . (plugin: http://tinyurl.com/7axlse4)

the content loads through Lightbox Plus wp plugin.

Can't get the lightbox to work after any switching of the month. Even when I change back to the initial month.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with Lightbox but for other plugins I am using a reload function after each Ajax request. Please, check [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

```
$.getScript("plugins/lightbox.js");
```