# Pretty Lightbox Not working after fetching data from Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, lightbox

I have developed a code to display all products when user lands on the page.. check below image

[image]

My Issue is that whenever user clicks on Category 01 or any other category checkbox, the Lightbox used on Product Box in right side gets disable.. Please note that after clicking on checkbox the data is fetched using AJAX function..

Below is my AJAX Code :

```
var xmlhttp=makeRequestObject();
ControlsArray=document.getElementsByTagName('input');


var products = "";
var productsAll = "";
var prodAll = true;

for(var i=0; i< ControlsArray.length; i++){


    if(ControlsArray[i].type=="checkbox" && ControlsArray[i].checked){
        if(ControlsArray[i].value == "All")
        {
            productsAll=ControlsArray[i].value + ",";

        }
        else
        {
            products+=ControlsArray[i].value + ",";
            prodAll = false;

        }
    }


}
if(prodAll == true)
{
    products = productsAll;
}

xmlhttp.open('GET', 'ajax-page.php?ID=1&SId='+products, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if(content){
            document.getElementById('Hint').innerHTML = content;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null)
}
```

My AJAX page code : (ajax-page.php)

```
<li>
        <div><a href='proDetails.php?proId=1&iframe=true&amp;width=620&amp;height=350' rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]"> <img src="img path" align="absmiddle" /></a></div>
       <div><a href='#'>Product 01</a></div></li>
```

Let me know what can we do to get Lightbox work when data is fetched from AJAX Control

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893406/lightbox-wont-work-after-ajax-content-update?rq=1

Comment: Hi Did you check the java error console? I am sure you have en error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Frndz..

I have resolved by passing lightbox jquery with ajax success..